# can someone tell me how to copy username & password info from one intent to website and press the login button

Tags: php, android

This is website I want to access with my app https://campusvirtual.uclm.es/login/index.php  but, I dont want to do it direcly. I´ve created another layout which the user will use to fill out his/her username & password. The problem is that the code doesnt work. this is how it looks like:
- **This is the code from the intent I want to copy to a website:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText uSer;
private EditText paS;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.cvlogin);

    uSer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user);
    paS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);

    Button web = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    web.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             load();
        }  
    }); 
}

protected void load(){ 

    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CVLogIn.class ); 
    //create a bundle
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putString("user_n",uSer.getText().toString());
    bundle.putString("pass_n",paS.getText().toString());

    // add the intent 

    i.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

}

**- Then here is website and, this is how i`ve wtitten the code:**

```
public class CVLogIn extends Activity {

private WebView myWebView;
private String uSer;
private String paS;

private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.seeweb);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);


    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Provide a WebViewClient for your WebView
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient()); 


    // Capturamos el intent creado en MainActivity
            Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
            if (bundle != null){
                myWebView.loadUrl("https://campusvirtual.uclm.es/login/index.php");
                //Recogemos los valores 
                uSer = bundle.getString("user_n");
                paS = bundle.getString("pass_n");

                myWebView.loadUrl("javascript: {" +
                        "document.getElementById('username').value = '"+uSer +"';" +
                        "document.getElementById('password').value = '"+paS+"';" +
                        "var frms = document.getElementsById('loginbtn');" +
                        "frms[0].submit(); };");     
            }

            // ProgressBar
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

            myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) 
                {               
                    progressBar.setProgress(0);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    progressBar.incrementProgressBy(progress);

                    if(progress == 100)
                    {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    // Check if there's history
    if (this.myWebView.canGoBack())
        this.myWebView.goBack();
    else
        super.onBackPressed();

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Forward button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoForward()) {
        myWebView.goForward();
        return true;
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("campusvirtual.uclm.es")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load
            // the page
            return false;
        }

        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch
        // another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the first `loadUrl()` is done loading before calling the second `loadUrl()`. `loadUrl()` is asynchronous, so the Web page is not loaded by the time you try running your JavaScript. Try doing the second `loadUrl()` [in `onPageFinished()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) and see if that helps.

Beyond that, test your JavaScript in a regular Web browser, using a JavaScript console (e.g., Firebug), and see if that shows any problems.